# Get value from URL and add one or subtract one (Next, previous button)

Tags: php, mysql

I would just like to thank you in advance for taking the time to read this. I ask that you please forgive me as I'm familiar with php but I'm by no means an expert. I have a developer create a website backend for my app and he up and left me high and dry to figure things out on my own.

I have a backend that is pulling info from a mySQL database. Each item is assigned a value. I'm using php to create a URL to edit each entry. So for instance when you click on the edit button it brings you to:

mysite.com/item/edit/1234

I'm trying to create a next and previous button that would add 1 (+1) to the url. So if I press next it would bring me to the next entry and would change the above URL to "mysite.com/item/edit/1235" and hitting the previous button would change the above URL to "mysite.com/item/edit/1233".

Please any help would be much appreciated. I've searched and searched and can't seem to find any solution that matches my problem.

Comment: Are you using any particular framework ?

Comment: Just print `basename($url)+1` for assembling the „next“ link, or whatever your actual input parameter is. (Show some code for concrete advise.)

Comment: It just uses PHP and JavaScript. That's as much as I know.

Comment: @mario Could you please explain how to do this. I apologize. Again I'm not very familiar with PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do just like this..
get the full url.. then get basename + 1

```
$url = "$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$next = basename($url) + 1;
```